# Intended use of the Unit Testing built in to CodeIgniter

Tags: unit-testing, codeigniter

In most framework unit testing implementations, you have a set of a tests and you execute those tests from a single [console] command. The tests run and a result is given. That result varies but generally it includes pass / fail.

CodeIgniter’s unit testing framework appears different and I have noticed an extensive collection of random tack-on-projects to either enhance or replace the CodeIgniter unit testing framework.

**My question is this**: What is the intended work flow or use of the unit testing framework built in to CodeIgniter?

I read the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/unit_testing.html); I get it. It’s a simple class. But where does one utilize the class?

For example, do all the tests go in to a single “test” controller? Or do the tests get intermingled in to each controller? Then there is the question of the models and custom helpers... Also, I'm assuming tests are run via a browser (or the alike) request...

Thanks for the guidance!

Regards,
Frank

Comment: Note: Most people will read 'CI' as Continuous Integration, might be worth pointing out early on that you mean Code Igniter (or even change the title)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've received an answer from [another source](https://web.archive.org/web/20121105212058/http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/172956) and I want to post it here since I am aware of it.

The basic answer is that the CI (CodeIgniter) unit test class is not intended like a traditional unit test suite (JUnit, NUnit, or python's unittest). In CI, the class is intended to be used within the target (the testing target's code base).

*To be clear: I'm not endorsing this nor am I sure this **is** the intended use of the CI [unit_test class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/unit_testing.html). This is just what I was told thus far. Perhaps others heard this too and can vote it up. If this is voted up or has support via comments, I'll mark this as an answer. I am still interested in differing opinions.*

Comment: For lack of any other answers, I'm marking this the answer. If your opinion differences, please comment or post your answer.

Comment: Hey Frank. The example Test controller that you posted on the CI forums was really helpful! Thanks for that! Instead of leaving the unit test controller in for production and using `$this->unit->active(false)` I'll probably just gitignore it so it doesn't get deployed... On second thought I might make it only available to logged in administrators. I've been unit testing like this for 30 minutes and my code is cleaner and I'm more productive already :)

Comment: I had the same question today, then I found this article. thank you very much, and your test controller example really taught me how to do unit testing in Codeigniter. you really save my day. :)

Comment: your source was deleted 404 Page Not Found

Comment: @FrankV Not so much as you can go back in time. Fixed it for you!