# Unit tests and functional tests in CodeIgniter

Tags: unit-testing, codeigniter, functional-testing

Is there any testing framework for CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the builtin [Unit testing framework](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/unit_testing.html), take a look as well at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145990/intended-use-of-the-unit-testing-built-in-to-codeigniter)

Answer (score 2):

Just a [simple one](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/unit_testing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Currently codeigniter doesn't have full supported unit testing. If your on the github repo however there is a branch the community is working on to add phpunit to the core. I would suggest cloning that repo and starting from there.

Comment: also until the release you can use http://code.ericlbarnes.com/codeigniter-simpletest/